# Hacks for JL&U Site

Tags: script, localisation, japanese

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

[image]

#### About

- Ruby support for pure links and text nodes

#### License

CC-BY-SA

#### Download

- https://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/show/104680
- how to install userscript - https://stackapps.com/tags/script/info

#### Platform

- Google Chrome (Tested only on Chrome 13 dev)
- Firefox with GreaseMonkey (Tested on Firefox 4.0.1, 5.0, 7.0a1)
- Opera (Tested only Opera 11.50)
- Safari with NinjaKit on Mac (Tested only on Safari 5.0 OSX 10.6.5)
- Internet Explorer with Trixie (Tested only on IE8)

#### Contact

mark at my-mm dot org

#### Code

Userscript (Javascript) using existing stackoverflow jQuery

source - https://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/review/104680

Comment: Sorry for asking what is probably a dumb question... but what does this script do?

Comment: @George, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_character (Furigana) for Japanese site, for now.

Comment: Great! Thanks - I'm completely clueless when it comes to Chinese / Japanese.

Comment: This completely breaks if `localStorage` is not available (and takes any other JS functionality of the site with it). Any particular reason it has to be `localStorage` and not cookies?

Comment: I have updated the copy we are using, so it is handles lack of `localStorage` gracefully.